# Фильтрация строк, содержащих числа, разделенные точкой с запятой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста регулярное выражения, чтобы оно пропускало строки вида 25;35;15, или 15, но не пропускало, к примеру, 15; - т.е. точка с запятой может только разделять цифры, но не стоять в конце.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Что-то наподобие

```
\d+(;\d+)*
```

должно сработать. Возможно, вам нужно

```
^\d+(;\d+)*$
```

(если в строке больше ничего не должно быть).